# RobotFramework: Aggregate report by grouping test suites using Rebot

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a test suite "my_test_suite.robot" like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    Log  Test 1

Test Case 2
    Log  Test 2
```

Then I run the pybot command twice as like this:

```
pybot --timestampoutputs my_test_suite.robot
```

So I get the reports two times. Now after that I ran the rebot command as follows:

```
rebot --name RebotCombined *.xml
```

It produced the neat combined report.html file where the high-level test suite is RebotCombined and two child test suites with the same name as "My Test Suite". i.e.,

```
RebotCombined
|
--- My Test Suite
|   |
|   --- Test Case 1
|   --- Test Case 2
--- My Test Suite
|   |
|   --- Test Case 1
|   --- Test Case 2
```

But what I was expecting is:

```
RebotCombined
|
--- My Test Suite
|   |
|   --- Test Case 1
|   --- Test Case 1
|   --- Test Case 2
|   --- Test Case 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your scenario you're running `Test Case 1` twice. However, in the "what I was expecting" section you show the test case listed only once. How does rebot decide which test case to show in the merged report? Or do you actually expect to see `Test Case 1` twice in the merged report?

Comment: Sorry @BryanOakley, did a mistake in the output. Now update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Rebot merely creates a new top-level suite and makes each output.xml file a child of that new top-level suite. It doesn't do any merging of data beyond that, except for updating the statistics.

All of the command line options for rebot are in the section [Command line options for post-processing outputs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#command-line-options-for-post-processing-outputs) in the user guide. It doesn't show any options that would give you the output you desire.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, it seems that this feature is going to be a part of RF 2.9. (https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1687)

Comment: @Vimal: possibly. It's not clear how that issue will handle the same test being run twice; it looks to be more about merging different subsets of tests.

Comment: Is there anyway to change the test case name during run time? So in my scenario, I want to change my Test Case 1 to Test Case 1_1. But it should happen during run time.

Comment: @Vimal: no, there is not.

Comment: We implemented issue #1687 mentioned above in RF 2.8.6. It does't alone provide functionality needed to support this use case, though, because tests with same name will be merged together when using `--merge`. Adding a separate cli option to control this behavior would be possible, however, so please submit a separate issue (preferably with a pull request) if you consider this important.